# CLI way to compress individual files currently in compressed folder

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a zipped file `Data.zip` that (if uncompressed) contains many files:

```
file_1.txt    
file_2.txt
...    
...
```

I want to have a CLI command to turn this into a new folder `Data_zipped`
that contains the individual files in `Data.zip` uncompressed:

```
Data_zipped/file_1.zip     
Data_zipped/file_2.zip
...
...
```

But the trick is that `Data.zip`  contains so many files (and they are collectively so big)  that I cannot first uncompress Data.zip and then compress the individual files inside it in one swoop: it all has to
happen 'on the fly':

For all files in `Data.zip/`

1. get the i-th file
2. compress it into `name_of_that_file.zip`
3. store the compressed file in the new folder `Data_zipped`

How to do that using the CLI?

I  modified [@George's](https://askubuntu.com/a/979650/522934) super clear script to help better explain the folder structure:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Name of zip file
filename=$1

# Check if valid zip file is passed
if [[ $(file "$filename" | grep -o "Zip archive data") =~ "Zip archive data" ]]
then    

        # List the contents of the zip file
        unzip -l "$filename" 

        # Get the number of files in zip file
        count=$(unzip -l "$filename" | awk '{count = $2 - 2} END {print count}')

        echo "$count"
    
fi

exit 0
```

When I run it I get (I use a token Data.zip with only a few files in it, but you get the idea):

```
./GU_script.sh Data.zip
Archive:  Data.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-11-21 22:58   Data/
120166309  2017-11-21 14:58   Data/Level1_file.csv
120887829  2017-11-21 14:58   Data/Level1_other_file.csv
163772796  2017-11-21 14:59   Data/Level1_yet_other_file.csv
193519556  2017-11-21 14:59   Data/Level1_here_is_another_file.csv
153798779  2017-11-21 14:59   Data/Level1_so_many_files.csv
131918225  2017-11-21 14:59   Data/Level1_many_more_to_go.csv
---------                     -------
884063494                     7 files
5
```

So basically, I would like `Level1_file.csv` and the other files to be zipped individually (-> Level1_file.zip) and put in a folder.

## Edit2;

I ended up combining @George's and @David Foerster's answers:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Name of zip file
filename="$1"

# Check if valid zip file is passed
if file "$filename" | grep -wq "Zip archive data";
then    

        #!/bin/bash
    src="$filename"
    dst=.

    LC_ALL=C unzip -l "$src" |
    sed -re '1,/^-{6}/d; /^-{6}/,$d; /\/$/d; s/^\s*(\S+\s+){3}//' |
    while IFS= read -r f; do
        out="${f##*/}"; out="$dst/${f%%/*}_zipped/${out%.*}.zip"
        if [ ! -d "${out%/*}" ]; then
        mkdir -p "${out%/*}" || break
        fi
        zip --copy "$src" --out "$out" "$f" || break
    done           

else
        echo "Invalid file type: \"zip\" file required"
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Have you looked at the "copy" (`-U`) operation of [`zip(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zip.1.html)? It copies *compressed* data from one archive to another without intermittent decompression.

Comment: The script is ready now you can test it and let me know the outcome!

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I tried that! When I do `zip Data.zip "*.csv" --copy --out Data_zipped` but that just creates a new zip file Data_zipped.zip identical to Data.zip ;(

Comment: `zip` cannot copy *to multiple* archives in a single invocation. See my answer for a full solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the “copy” operation of [`zip(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zip.1.html) and some file path mangling. It has the advantage to copy compressed data streams directly to the target archive without intermittent decompression.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
src=Data.zip
dst=.

LC_ALL=C unzip -l "$src" |
sed -re '1,/^-{6}/d; /^-{6}/,$d; /\/$/d; s/^\s*(\S+\s+){3}//' |
while read -r f; do
    out="${f##*/}"; out="$dst/${f%%/*}_zipped/${out%.*}.zip"
    if [ ! -d "${out%/*}" ]; then
        mkdir -p "${out%/*}" || return
    fi
    zip --copy "$src" --out "$out" "$f" <&- || return
done
```

I added `LC_ALL=C` to the invocation of `unzip` because its output format looks a little flaky across different implementations and I want to avoid locale-dependent output variants at least.

Answer (score 3):

This should be able to do what you want:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Name of zip file
filename="$1"

# Check if valid zip file is passed
if file "$filename" | grep -wq "Zip archive data";
then    

        # List the contents of the zip file
        unzip -l "$filename" 

        # Make the destination folder
        # after checking they don't exist
        if [ ! -d Data_zipped ]; 
        then
                mkdir Data_zipped
        fi
        #make temporary folder
        #for extracted files
        tempdir=$(mktemp -d)            
        # Make temporary file to hold the filenames
        mysrc=$(mktemp)

        # Get the filesnames from the zip folder
        unzip -c Data.zip | cut -d" " -f3- | grep -E -o "[^Data/].*" | grep -Ev \(.zip\) | sed '/^\s*$/d' > "$mysrc"           

        while read -r var;
        do
                unzip -j "$filename" "Data/$var" -d "$tempdir/"                    
                # Get name of file from each read line
                zip Data_zipped/"$var".zip "$tempdir/$var"
                # remove the original file
                rm -rf "$tempdir/${var:?}"

        done < "$mysrc"           

else
        echo "Invalid file type: \"zip\" file required"
        exit 1
fi
```

**Note**:

Tree structure used:

```
Data
├── file_10.txt
├── file_1.txt
...
```

Comment: Ok I guess a wildcard `*` should be sufficient then?

Comment: Let me modify it!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think there is still a problem. When I do `./GU_unzip.sh Data.zip`  I get zillions of errors like this one: `caution: filename not matched:  Data/Data/FMV0017!","O","47.450000","6",""
 zip warning: name not matched: ftmp/FMV0017!","O","47.450000","6",""
.zip)rror: Nothing to do! (Data_zipped/FMV0017!","O","47.450000","6",""
Archive:  Data.zip` [I think the `FMV0017!...` strings  are individual data lines of the csv files]

Comment: @user2413 is there a `Data` folder inside`Data.zip`? The structure must match that which you gave us!

Comment: @dessert great learning moment for me, thanks will update the script!

Comment: @George; Indeed: I thought there was a folder inside but I was mistaken (confused rather by the behavior of the zip program). So to confirm, the files are  `Data.zip/file_names.csv`. I tried modifying your script by removing the second `/Data` everywhere, but I could not get the changed version to work). Sorry about that.

Comment: Hold on I will provide a better and updated version thanks to @dessert

Comment: @user2413 see my updated script that should handle your new folder structor!

Comment: @George: still get `.zip)rror: Nothing to do! (Data_zipped/FMQ0017!","O","46.840000","6",""
Archive:  Data.zip
caution: filename not matched:  Data/FMU0017!","B","47.090000","1",""
 zip warning: name not matched: /tmp/tmp.u1ry18nQNM/FMU0017!","B","47.090000","1",""`:(

Comment: Yes @dessert that what I want works on my end but let me test it again! This is what I get and is what I want `file_9.txt        
file_7.txt        
file_8.txt        
file_5.txt        
file_3.txt        
file_4.txt        
file_2.txt        
file_1.txt        
file_10.txt       
file_6.txt    ` So works from my end

Comment: @Dessert modified it to give me what I want and it's a bit longer: `unzip -l Data3.zip | head -n-2 | awk 'NR>3{print $4}' | sed -e 's/^Data\///' -e '/^\s*$/d'`

Comment: OP said he wanted the files listed that's why I have that line there @dessert

Comment: I ended up picking @David Foerster's solution because it avoids the intermediate compression/decompression. But I combined his idea with the interface you wrote since it was super convenient to use;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered looking into a [fuse filesystem with zip-support](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip)?

This basically exposes the zip file as a regular directory, which any application may open and read files from, whilst the fuse library handles the dirty details of reading and writing the compressed stream.

On Ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt install fuse-zip`

After installing fuse-zip you can mount a zip-file with `fuse-zip /path/to/some.zip mnt/`, where mnt is an empty directory of your choosing.

After finishing, unmount it with `fusermount -u mnt/`, where mnt is the directory where you mounted it.

fuse-zip will even create the zip on the fly for you, if it doesn't excist.

Answer (score 1):

you can unzip the files contained in Data.zip one by one:
`unzip Data.zip file1.txt` 
and compress them.

```bsh
mkdir Data_unzipped  
for i in `seq 1 100`  # or whatever the number of your files is
do
  unzip Data.zip file_${i}.txt
  zip Data_unzipped/file_${i}.zip file_${i}.txt
  rm file_${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: Can this be done with a 'for all files in `Data.zip/Data/`' I don't actually have a simple repetitive file name structure inside `Data.zip/Data/` I am editing the question to better target the problem (sorry about the first version of the question being a bit off)?

Comment: You can get a list of your files with `unzip -l Data.zip > /tmp/files`, then edit the resulting file so that it contains only your file names (e.g. with cut). Then you can use a loop:
    for i in \`cat /tmp/files\` do ...
BTW: I forgot to delete the uncompressed files in my above script (edited now).

Comment: `\`seq 1 100\`` can be replaced by `{1..100}` in `bash`, this is [Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace).